# How to copy a bundle html file to a document directory in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview, nsfilemanager

I have been trying to save local index.html file to document directory but it does not save to local document directory.

here is my folder structure:

```
sampleHtml.xcodeproj
---->sampleHtml
-------->Web_Assets
------------> index.html
---->ViewController.swift
```

Here is the code for saving and checking file path exist is not, if path exist then overwrite it else copy the new one.

```
func saveHtmlDoc(){
    let filemgr = FileManager.default
    let docURL = filemgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let destPath = docURL.path+"/www/"
    print("des path", destPath)
    let sourcePath = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent("Web_Assets").path
    print("sourc", sourcePath.appending("/index.html"))

      //COPY Web_Assets content from Bundle to Documents/www
      do {
          try filemgr.removeItem(atPath: destPath)
      } catch {
          print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
      do {
          try filemgr.copyItem(atPath:  sourcePath + "/", toPath: destPath)
      } catch {
          print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }

}
```

My issue is how to save index.html file to document directory and check the file path exist are not, if exist overwrite it or copy the new one.

Any help much appreciates it...

Comment: source path points to the directory, not the html file. Have you tried just copying the file instead of the folder

Comment: i have been trying web_assets folder to documentary. web_assets folder contains index.html.

Comment: trying to save path like ...Documents/www/index.html

Comment: try copying file to folder instead of folder to folder

Comment: @Scriptable tried but it does not work. it shows error. des path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C1D31B69-F1FE-4A35-BAA9-75F70E34D06F/Documents/www/
sourc /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/03C28303-EBA2-4FA2-83E9-04092855479B/sampleHtml.app/index.html/index.html
Error: “www” couldn’t be removed.
Error: The file “index.html” couldn’t be opened.

Comment: `sampleHtml.app/index.html/index.html`????

Comment: @Scriptable now it showing like this des path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FBD460E5-7953-488C-9EBB-D59B215EB69E/Documents/www/
sourc /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9D16361B-6DAD-4C50-9E9C-652EB5DFBB00/sampleHtml.app/index.html
2020-02-18 15:15:30.735576+0530 sampleHtml[1349:287945] open on /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FBD460E5-7953-488C-9EBB-D59B215EB69E/Documents/www/: No such file or directory
Error: The file “index.html” doesn’t exist.

Comment: @Scriptable changed bundle Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent("index.html", isDirectory: true).path

Comment: you can use fileManager.fileExists(atPath:) to test path is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just done this code in a test project which works.

You should ensure that you are performing checks along the way and ensure that your HTML file is in your Copy resources build phase

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        moveHtmlFile()
    }

    private func moveHtmlFile() {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        guard let sourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html") else {
            return
        }

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: sourcePath) {
            let sourceUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: sourcePath)
            try? fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("www").path,
                                             withIntermediateDirectories: false,
                                             attributes: nil)
            let destination = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("www/index.html", isDirectory: false)
            try? fileManager.copyItem(at: sourceUrl, to: destination)

            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destination.path) {
                print("file copied")
            } else {
                print("file copy failed")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: how to print the copied path.

Comment: I tried your code and this just create file `www` not copy file `index.html` to www folder

Comment: try the other answer which uses createDirectory

Comment: @ParameswaranV i just updated the code and confirmed folder and index.html file created and index.html file contains same contents as bundle file.

Comment: how to print copied file path url

Comment: `print(destination.path)`

Comment: Did this fix your issue?

Answer (score 3):

I try and test below code, it work okey. Before add file, you need create folder first.

```
func saveHtmlDoc() {
    let filemgr = FileManager.default
    let docURL = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let destPath = URL(string:docURL)?.appendingPathComponent("www")

    guard let newDestPath = destPath, let sourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "image", ofType: ".png"), let fullDestPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: newDestPath.absoluteString).appendingPathComponent("image.png") else { return  }

    //CREATE FOLDER
    if !filemgr.fileExists(atPath: newDestPath.path) {
        do {
            try filemgr.createDirectory(atPath: newDestPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Folder is exist")
    }

    if filemgr.fileExists(atPath: fullDestPath.path) {
        print("File is exist in \(fullDestPath.path)")
    }
    else {
        do {
            try filemgr.copyItem(atPath:  sourcePath, toPath: fullDestPath.path)
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows error des path Optional(/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3145E00B-6387-494B-A197-965C57A5042B/Documents/www)
Error: “index.html” couldn’t be removed.
2020-02-18 16:05:19.516677+0530 sampleHtml[1433:305213] open on /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3145E00B-6387-494B-A197-965C57A5042B/Documents/www/index.html: Not a directory
Error: “index.html” couldn’t be copied to “www”.

Comment: @ParameswaranV This log error because your folder and file is exist, check my update code.